# Week date Range in T-sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
declare @startdate datetime='11/30/2012',@enddate datetime='12/6/2012'
Select 
Convert(varchar, DateAdd(dd, -(DatePart(dw, @startdate) - 1), @startdate), 101) As WeekStart,
Convert(varchar, DateAdd(dd, (7 - DatePart(dw, @enddate)), @enddate), 101) As WeekEnd
```

Above is the code and the output of the code is:

```
11/25 2012  12/08/2012
```

But I want to show separate the result over 2 weeks.  Please how can I show the data in this format?

```
11/25/2012  12/01/2012 ( 1 week)
12/02/2012  12/08/2012 ( 2 week)
```

Comment: What's your application? You'll need to loop over the date range to create each week record. SQL probably isn't the best choice here.

Comment: what exactly are you asking for ? Do you want all weeks between the 2 dates, or just the weeks in the variables ?

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms181598.aspx) to set start of week!
The code below gives desired result. SQL-Fiddle-Link at the bottom.

```
declare @startdate  date = '2012-11-30';
declare @enddate    date = '2012-12-06';

with "nums"
as
(
  select 1 as "value"
  union all select "value" + 1 as "value"
  from "nums"
  where "value" <= 52
)
, "intervals"
as
(
  select
  "id" = "value"
  , "startDate" = cast( dateadd( week, "value" - 1, dateadd(year, datediff(year, 0, getdate()), 0)) as date )
  , "endDate" = cast( dateadd( week, "value", dateadd( year, datediff( year, 0, getdate()), 0 )) as date )

from
  "nums"
)
select
    "startDate", "endDate", row_number() over ( order by rand() ) as "number"
from
    "intervals"
where
    "startDate" <= @startdate and "endDate" > @startdate
    or
    "startDate" <= @enddate and "endDate" > @enddate
```

[see SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/7285/0)